# I can not remove Ruby1.9.3p0 from ubuntu. What is the process?

Tags: uninstall, ruby, versions

I have installed `ruby 1.9.3p0` and on executing the command `ruby -v` it shows the version `1.9.3p0` installed. When i try to remove it by command `sudo apt-get remove ruby1.9.3p0` it says `package not found so not removed`. What should I do?

Comment: What does it do if you try to remove it via Ubuntu Software Center?

Comment: It doesnt show up in the software center

Comment: What's the output of `dpkg -l | grep ruby`?

Comment: i  libruby1.9.1                           1.9.3.0-1ubuntu2.5                      Libraries necessary to run Ruby 1.9.1
rc  ruby1.9.1                              1.9.3.0-1ubuntu2.5                      Interpreter of object-oriented scripting language Rub

Comment: When you say "I have installed ruby 1.9.3p0", how exactly did you install it? This will provide clues on how to remove it. No Ubuntu packages report version 1.9.3p0 so I wonder where this was isntalled from.

Answer (score 4):

The package name is ruby1.9.1 but the software version is 1.9.3, so remove it running:

```
sudo apt-get remove ruby1.9.1 libruby1.9.1
```

Comment: the command sudo apt-get autoremove ruby1.9.1 removed something but the ruby -v command still shows the version 1.9.3 installed

Comment: the remove command did nothing

Comment: Please edit your question and include the output of the commands you ran. Run `dpkg -l | grep ruby` again and post its output.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure when you run ruby you are running system ruby and not rvm or rbenv ruby?

```
$ which ruby
/home/jrwren/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/ruby
```

/usr/bin/ruby uses alternatives - you can read more with man update-alternatives

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/ruby
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Oct 11  2011 /usr/bin/ruby -> /etc/alternatives/ruby
$ ls -l /etc/alternatives/ruby
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Oct 12 16:57 /etc/alternatives/ruby -> /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
```

So ultimately ruby is a symlink to /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1  You can ask dpkg to which package this file belongs with -S

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
ruby1.9.1: /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
```

And remove that package

```
$ sudo apt-get remove ruby1.9.1
```

At this point the alternatives system will kick in and symlink /usr/bin/ruby to another ruby version on your system if you have it. Mine found a ruby 1.8. Repeat the process if you with to remove that version.

Answer (score 1):

Just simply try `sudo apt-get remove ruby`, Or type `sudo apt-get remove ruby` and before pressing `Enter` press `Tab` multiple times to see what you can remove about ruby.

Comment: Not working. pressing tab shows the version 1.9.1

Comment: and if is continue to remove it it says package not found

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get purge ruby
```

And press Tab multiple times to see what you can remove about ruby. After, check with

```
dpkg -l | grep ruby
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
     sudo apt-get --purge remove ruby1.9.3p0
```

It will remove all dependency packages also.